# Media9 compiles but embedded video gives "Unable to connect to content" "TypeError - Error #1009"

Tags: beamer, pdf, luatex, media9, multimedia

I have a `beamer` presentation that I am creating and I'm trying to embed a video clip. I'm using the `media9` package and having a ton of issues with it. I've gone through the documentation with a fine-toothed comb but I'm still striking out. Here's what I have done so far:

First, I modified the video file into `MP4/H.264` using `ffmpeg` as the `media9` documentation instructs. The code I used is directly from the documentation:

```
ffmpeg -i /filepath/file.mp4 -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -c:v
           libx264 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 30 -r 30 /filepath/file2.mp4
```

Then, I added this code to my `beamer` presentation:

```
\includemedia[
    width=0.7\linewidth,
    height=0.5\linewidth,
    activate=onclick,
    addresource=/filepath/file2.MP4,
    flashvars={source=/filepath/file2.MP4}
  ]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
```

After doing this, the presentation compiles fully with no errors or notes in the console about `media9`, the file, or anything related to the video.

However, when I open it in Adobe Acrobat Pro x (Mac OS X 10.10.3), I get the error `We are unable to connect to the content you've requested. We apologize for the inconvenience.` After clicking around the video, the message will change and display `TypeError - Error #1009`

I've tried using `VPlayer.swf` instead and that didn't work. I've tried using different settings on `ffmpeg` to convert the video differently, and I'm just not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: Two errors: (1)  In Strobe, the correct FlashVar is `src` not `source` (which is VPlayer).  (2) The `ffmpeg` generated file is `file2.mp4`, but you try to embed  `file2.MP4`. Case matters.

Comment: Use `.flv` format rather than `.mp4`. I also had exactly the same issue, and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

The correct FlashVar for setting the video source in `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` is

```
src=/filepath/file2.MP4
```

otherwise, the reported error occurs.

The following MWE should work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\includemedia[
    width=0.7\linewidth,
    height=0.5\linewidth,
%    activate=onclick, %this is default
    addresource=/filepath/file2.MP4,
    flashvars={src=/filepath/file2.MP4}
  ]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue you're describing.  I was only able to successfully embed the video when `filepath` is in the same directory as my `beamer.tex` file.

This is particularly confusing because I'm not aware that this limitation is spelled out in the `media9` documentation.

Comment: This statement is not true.

Comment: This probably should be a comment rather than an answer, since it isn't an answer, really.

Comment: This is indeed true on my system (MacTeX-2015, OS X 10.10.3).  I should have clarified that the movie files can be in a separate directory, that directory just needs to be at the level of the main Beamer file.  Specifying `./path/file.mp4` for `addresource` and `flashvars={src` works while using `../path/file.mp4` does not.

Comment: For this particular case you can use `\addmediapath{../filepath}` to add a non-sublevel dir to the search path and omit the path within `\includemedia`. FlashPlayer doesn't allow relative paths outside the current directory for security reasons. Absolute paths to media files, even outside the current directory tree, should work as expected.